# What is the reason of this error 'it' was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

What is the reason of this error in this case?

> 'it' was not declared in this scope

I don't understand why I get that error, I defined `it` in statement of `for loop`..

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
void LoopFunction() {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    for (std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) { // **error in this line**
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @NathanOliver What is not good with my question? I aksed exactly what is the problem..

Comment: `vector<T>::iterator` Maybe you forgot to prefix it with `std::`?

Comment: @Software_t Your question is missing information.  For instance, do you have a `using namespace std;` before this code?

Comment: I'm wondering if it also requires `typename`, i.e. `for (typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin(); ...`

Comment: @FredLarson it's working now! can you explain why please?

Comment: [Dependent names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

Comment: Since you are using C++11, just write `for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) { ... }` or even better: `for (auto const& element : vec) { ... }`